# Multiple display form for SharePoint list

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

I'm building custom .net application for SharePoint 2010 which is running from _layouts folder. It has multiple survey form(aspx) and all create records in one list. I want to open the respective form when edit item link is clicked in SP view.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can create a content type for your list and add the formurl element to the content type like so

```
<XmlDocuments> 
<XmlDocument  NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url"> 
  <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url"> 
   <Display>_Layouts/xyzCorp/BZH_xMgt.aspx</Display> 
   <Edit>_Layouts/xyzCorp/BZH_xMgt.aspx</Edit> 
   <New>_Layouts/xyzCorp/BZH_xMgt.aspx</New> 
 </FormUrls> 
</XmlDocument>
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473210(v=office.12).aspx)

I believe, but haven't tested, that your pages will received an ID=xxx in the querystring.

---

Rather than building custom application pages in _layouts I would recommend building custom form templates which allows you to reuse a lot of standard SharePoint functionality:

- Standard field controls (no need to do CRUD)
- Reuse standard functions such as save, cancel, version control
- Reuse your existing branding
- Add functionality to your form using the ribbon

For anexamples see http://blogs.syrinx.com/blogs/sharepoint/archive/2008/11/10/custom-item-layouts-using-custom-form-templates.aspx.